# How to list file descriptors of any command before it finishes?

Tags: process, file-descriptors

File descriptors can be easily listed by executing `ls -l /proc/$PID_OF_RUNNING_OR_PAUSED_PROCESS/fd/`. But the commmand has to be running or paused at time of listing in order file descriptors still exist. How can I do the same for processes that finish right after execution? Is there any way to pause a command right after its execution? (e.g. `ls -l /var/log/messages`)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine? The open file descriptors, I get that, but what are you hoping that’s going to tell you?

Comment: this is only for educational purposes. I'm just trying to see clear picture of file descriptors and linked open files of some commands. nothing extra special

Comment: I tried solutions from https://goo.gl/cBefJT but file descriptors seems to be created for parent process not for target command. They do not change no mather what target command is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a process through `strace` and have it show you all opened files (and directories):

```
strace -o cmd.strace -e trace=open cmd
```

Comment: Yes, this is a much more robust approach than trying to get a snapshot of open file descriptors. Other `trace` filters which could be useful here are `file` (all system calls taking a file name as argument), `desc` (all file descriptor-related system calls) and `memory` (all memory mapping-related system calls, including `mmap2`).